# I want to know if is possible to build the OpenCV Java library for a embebed system with a architecture armv7?

Tags: java, opencv, armv7

well i'm trying to develop an application for a beagleBone black (armv7) with the jdk installed. If it's possible, can say me how to do it? I use the cross-compiler recommended in the page of openCV for embebed system but it only generate me a c++ library, and I need the .jar whit the .so file.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html#arm-linux-cross-compile

Answer (score 0):

I have developed application in OpenCV for BeagleboneBlack. But this application is in C++. All you need are the arm compatible .so files. Just download the binary package of JavaCV. Extract it, you will find the binaries for Android. These are compiled for arm devices. Use these libraries for Beaglebone.

Hope it will solve your problem.